# Are cookies in UIWebView accepted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cookies, uiwebview

I have to question for you.

1 : I'm using `UIWebView`s in my iPhone App. I wan't the users be able to add comments in the news. But, to comment they have to log-in.

If not, how can I accept cookies in `UIWebView`s ?

2 : Are the cookies created in on `UIWebView` available in others `UIWebView` in an other View ?

Ex : I have my `LoginViewController`, with an embedded `UIWebView`, where my user can login/logout. If they log-in in this view, the cookie will be still available in the `CommentViewController` ?

If not, how can I make this possible ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `UIWebView` will automatically store the cookies in the `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` collection, and should be available in all other `UIWebView`s within your app, during the same app launch. However the `UIWebView` class does not automatically store cookies for the pages that are loaded between app launches. You need to manually store cookies when the app is moved into the background and reload the values when the app is brought back into the foreground.

Place the following code in your AppDelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Other existing code

    [self loadHTTPCookies];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //Other existing code

    [self saveHTTPCookies];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self loadHTTPCookies];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //Other existing code
    [self saveHTTPCookies];
}

-(void)loadHTTPCookies
{
    NSMutableArray* cookieDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"cookieArray"];

    for (int i=0; i < cookieDictionary.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* cookieDictionary1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[cookieDictionary objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieDictionary1];
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
    }
}

-(void)saveHTTPCookies
{
    NSMutableArray *cookieArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
        [cookieArray addObject:cookie.name];
        NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [cookieProperties setObject:cookie.name forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
        [cookieProperties setObject:cookie.value forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
        [cookieProperties setObject:cookie.domain forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
        [cookieProperties setObject:cookie.path forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
        [cookieProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:cookie.version] forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];
        [cookieProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2629743] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:cookieProperties forKey:cookie.name];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:cookieArray forKey:@"cookieArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: @jan it should work, since this code stores the entire cookie collection, regardless of domain.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this solution via php?

Comment: is it working with ios10 and onwards? i am unable to get cookies in ios11.

Answer (score 11):

*Expanding the other answers:*

Since `NSHTTPCookieStorage cookies` can be archived using `NSKeyedArchiver`, you don't need to extract every single cookie property yourself. Furthermore, you will want to remove the `NSUserDefaults` cookie property, when there are no cookies to store.

So you can simplify your cookie storing/loading to this extension:

```
static NSString *const kCookiesKey = @"cookies";

@implementation NSHTTPCookieStorage (Persistence)

- (void)saveToUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (self.cookies != nil && self.cookies.count > 0) {
        NSData *cookieData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.cookies];
        [userDefaults setObject:cookieData forKey:kCookiesKey];
    } else {
        [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:kCookiesKey];
    }
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}

- (void)loadFromUserDefaults
{
    NSData *cookieData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCookiesKey];
    if (cookieData != nil) {
        NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookieData];
        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
            [self setCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Then just use `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] loadFromUserDefaults];` and `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] saveToUserDefaults];` in your `AppDelegate` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

## swift 3 clear version

```
func saveCookies() {
    guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies else {
        return
    }
    let array = cookies.flatMap { (cookie) -> [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]? in
        cookie.properties
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "cookies")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

func loadCookies() {
    guard let cookies = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cookies") as? [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]] else {
        return
    }
    cookies.forEach { (cookie) in
        guard let cookie = HTTPCookie.init(properties: cookie) else {
            return
        }
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

From all the great other answers to this question I compiled a handy extension on `UserDefaults` that shortens the necessary code.

#### `UserDefaults` Extension for Swift 3

```
extension UserDefaults {

    /// A dictionary of properties representing a cookie.
    typealias CookieProperties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]

    /// The `UserDefaults` key for accessing cookies.
    private static let cookieKey = "cookies"

    /// Saves all cookies currently in the shared `HTTPCookieStorage` to the shared `UserDefaults`.
    func saveCookies() {
        guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies else {
            return
        }
        let cookiePropertiesArray = cookies.flatMap { $0.properties }
        set(cookiePropertiesArray, forKey: UserDefaults.cookieKey)
        synchronize()
    }

    /// Loads all cookies stored in the shared `UserDefaults` and adds them to the current shared `HTTPCookieStorage`.
    func loadCoookies() {
        let cookiePropertiesArray = value(forKey: UserDefaults.cookieKey) as? [CookieProperties]
        cookiePropertiesArray?.forEach {
            if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: $0) {
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can add this code to a separate file `UserDefaults+Cookies.swift` (for example) and then call the methods from your `AppDelegate` as described by Brian Shamblen in his [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006163/2062785):

#### Calls from AppDelegate

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.loadCoookies()
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.loadCoookies()
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.saveCookies()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.saveCookies()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any] ? ) - > Bool {
    loadHTTPCookies()

    return true
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    saveCookies()
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    loadHTTPCookies()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    saveCookies()
}

func loadHTTPCookies() {

    if let cookieDict = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cookieArray") as? NSMutableArray {

        for c in cookieDict {

            let cookies = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: c as!String) as!NSDictionary
            let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookies as![HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any])

            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie!)
        }
    }
}

func saveCookies() {

    let cookieArray = NSMutableArray()
    if let savedC = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
        for c: HTTPCookie in savedC {

            let cookieProps = NSMutableDictionary()
            cookieArray.add(c.name)
            cookieProps.setValue(c.name, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name.rawValue)
            cookieProps.setValue(c.value, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value.rawValue)
            cookieProps.setValue(c.domain, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain.rawValue)
            cookieProps.setValue(c.path, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path.rawValue)
            cookieProps.setValue(c.version, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version.rawValue)
            cookieProps.setValue(NSDate().addingTimeInterval(2629743), forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires.rawValue)

            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(cookieProps, forKey: c.name)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(cookieArray, forKey: "cookieArray")
}
```

Comment: can you help me here ? this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860796/cookies-don%C2%B4t-keep-user-logged-in-in-swift3/41864952#41864952

Comment: There was a typing mistake in the code above i fixed it and i also answered your question thank you for pointing that there was a problem

Answer (score 3):

Here is a cleaner and more safe **Swift** version:

```
private func loadCookies() {
    guard let cookies = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("cookies") as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
        return
    }

    for cookieProperties in cookies {
        if let cookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties) {
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}

private func saveCookies() {
    guard let cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies else {
        return
    }

    var array = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    for cookie in cookies {
        if let properties = cookie.properties {
            array.append(properties)
        }
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(array, forKey: "cookies")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Comment: any way to first time i load webview with manually cookies through  API or other way. so automatically login.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

Please add this extension to your controller

```
extension UserDefaults {

    /// A dictionary of properties representing a cookie.
    typealias CookieProperties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]

    /// The `UserDefaults` key for accessing cookies.
    private static let cookieKey = "cookies"

    /// Saves all cookies currently in the shared `HTTPCookieStorage` to the shared `UserDefaults`.
    func saveCookies() {
        guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies else {
            return
        }
        let cookiePropertiesArray = cookies.compactMap { $0.properties }
        set(cookiePropertiesArray, forKey: UserDefaults.cookieKey)
        synchronize()
    }

    /// Loads all cookies stored in the shared `UserDefaults` and adds them to the current shared `HTTPCookieStorage`.
    func loadCoookies() {
        let cookiePropertiesArray = value(forKey: UserDefaults.cookieKey) as? [CookieProperties]
        cookiePropertiesArray?.forEach {
            if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: $0) {
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And replace in AppDelegate this code lines:

```
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
```

with this code lines:

```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.loadCoookies()
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.loadCoookies()
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.saveCookies()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.saveCookies()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.0 Version**

```
func loadCookies() {

    let cookieDict : NSMutableArray? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("cookieArray") as? NSMutableArray

    if cookieDict != nil {

        for var c in cookieDict! {

            let cookies = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(c as! String) as! NSDictionary
            let cookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookies as! [String : AnyObject])

            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie!)
        }
    }
}

func saveCookies() {

    var cookieArray = NSMutableArray()
    let savedC = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies

    for var c : NSHTTPCookie in savedC! {

        var cookieProps = NSMutableDictionary()
        cookieArray.addObject(c.name)
        cookieProps.setValue(c.name, forKey: NSHTTPCookieName)
        cookieProps.setValue(c.value, forKey: NSHTTPCookieValue)
        cookieProps.setValue(c.domain, forKey: NSHTTPCookieDomain)
        cookieProps.setValue(c.path, forKey: NSHTTPCookiePath)
        cookieProps.setValue(c.version, forKey: NSHTTPCookieVersion)
        cookieProps.setValue(NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(2629743), forKey: NSHTTPCookieExpires)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(cookieProps, forKey: c.name)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(cookieArray, forKey: "cookieArray")
}
```