# Cookies don´t keep user logged in in swift3

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, swift3

I have this simple application with a UIWebView, but I can not use the cookies to store the loggin or keep the user logged.

I open the application, I log in, I close the application, and when I open it again the login fields are blank.
I would like at least that the user and password were filled based on cookies

this is the code from viewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = URL(string: "https://dashboardgrouping.correadasilva.com")

        myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:url!))


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)->Bool {
        loadHTTPCookies()

        return true
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        saveCookies()
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        loadHTTPCookies()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        saveCookies()
    }

    func loadHTTPCookies() {

        if let cookieDict = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cookieArray") as?NSMutableArray {

            for c in cookieDict {

                let cookies = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: c as!String) as!NSDictionary
                let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookies as![HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any])

                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie!)
            }
        }
    }

    func saveCookies() {

        let cookieArray = NSMutableArray()
        if let savedC = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
            for c: HTTPCookie in savedC {

                let cookieProps = NSMutableDictionary()
                cookieArray.add(c.name)
                cookieProps.setValue(c.name, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name.rawValue)
                cookieProps.setValue(c.value, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value.rawValue)
                cookieProps.setValue(c.domain, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain.rawValue)
                cookieProps.setValue(c.path, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path.rawValue)
                cookieProps.setValue(c.version, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version.rawValue)
                 cookieProps.setValue(NSDate().addingTimeInterval(2629743), forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires.rawValue)

                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(cookieProps, forKey: c.name)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(cookieArray, forKey: "cookieArray")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done half of the work here which is great but

You need to call `loadHTTPCookies()` and `saveCookies()` in `AppDelegate.swift` file and not in your viewController

I built you a sample project to take a look at:
https://github.com/omiz/Cookies

Comment: Hello @zombie, thanks for the response, I downloaded your project and tested it, but it does not do what I'm trying to do.
What I want is that after the user enters the site, and close the application by the task manager, when he reopens the application the user fields and password of the form come with the user and password filled automatically according to the previous login.

Will this code for cookies code do this?

Comment: this sample will save the cookies i.e. if a user logged in they will stay in. Saving the user data and for the next try is not tested but i think it should be something else

Answer (score 0):

I think the function `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:` never been called due to its a function of `UIApplicationDelegate`.
Most of the time you only have these functions on `AppDelegate` which implement `UIApplicationDelegate` by default

Please try to

**Move** your `loadHTTPCookies()` to `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

OR

**Move** the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:` back to the class where `UIApplicationDelegate` implemented (e,g AppDelegate)

Comment: Hello, I actually created the functions in the wrong place, but even changing to the appDelegate.swift file still did not work.