# How I can allow web pages cookies in my xcode swift 3 webview?

Tags: swift, xcode, cookies, webview

I have a problem with my Swift 3 program. I want to allow web pages cookies in my XCode webview. Can you help me?

Many thanks for your help!

greeting
Bjoern

Comment: @Bjoern follow `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005641/are-cookies-in-uiwebview-accepted` . it will helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
var req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
var cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as! [NSHTTPCookie]
var reqCookies:[AnyObject] = []
for aCookie in cookies {
    reqCookies += [aCookie]
}
var headers = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(reqCookies)
self.webView.loadRequest(req)
```

Comment: Where did you use headers here ??